# Spring Boot - Unable to send email with attachments

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to send the email with attachments but the email is missing the attachments. I tried with both classpath resource and file placed in a path. Both are not working. Below is the code I am using:

```
//Service Impl class



 @Autowired
        JavaMailSender emailSender;

  private void sendEmail(){
         MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
                                 MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

                                 helper.setSubject("Attachment email");
                                 helper.setText("Test email for Spring boot email service");
                                 helper.setTo("sample@company.com");
                                 helper.setFrom("noreply@company.com");

                                //using as class path resource
     //helper.addAttachment("Resume.pdf", new ClassPathResource("resume.pdf"));


                                    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource("C:\\test\resume.pdf");
                                    helper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
                                 emailSender.send(message);
        }
```

**Email Configuration:**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.company.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.mail.default.from.address=noeply@company.com
```

**Spring Boot version:**

```
Spring Boot 2.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the pathname that you are passing is not correct pathname for java. A backslash is used to escape characters in java. In Java, you have to use forward slash as a path separator. In any case, hardcoding a file path is a bad practice but you can change the FileSystemResource as below and it should work.

> FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource("C:/test/resume.pdf");

Comment: I changed the path name as you said. Still no change only email is sent with no attachments.

Comment: Can you verify if you are able to read the file by putting a log statement after checking file.isReadable()